# Kaldi speaker text-independet recognize

Tags: распознавание-речи, kaldi

Я новичок в Kaldi, но задача стоит грандиозная. Необходимо написать код C++ для обучения i-vector extractor и использовать его для тексто-независимого распознавания диктора. Есть у кого нибудь код для примера, библиотека так сложна для понимания?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше xvector использовать, а не ivector.

Тренировать extractor в c++ ненужно, можно готовый скачать или натренировать отдельно. Код для извлечения ivectorа и для сравнения [тут](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/bd1da143a19c5686d9a00da7885b428d621bd748/src/ivectorbin/ivector-extract.cc#L46), всего 5 строчек:

```
    IvectorExtractorUtteranceStats utt_stats(extractor_.NumGauss(),
                                            extractor_.FeatDim(),
                                            false);
    utt_stats.AccStats(feats_, posterior_);
    ivector_.Resize(extractor_.IvectorDim());
    ivector_(0) = extractor_.PriorOffset();
    extractor_.GetIvectorDistribution(utt_stats, &ivector_, NULL);
```

Comment: Ответил Вам ниже)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Ваш ответ вызвал у меня ряд вопросов. Почему не нужно тренировать i-vector в С++, если я планирую использовать алгоритм обучения в своем приложении. Насколько я понимаю, для обучения экстрактора нужно две модели GMM диктора и GMM-UBM толпы, соответственно их нужно каким-то образом подготовить и в коде Kaldi в явном или нет виде должно присутствовать, т.е. библиотека должна предоставлять каркас, где этот момент проходит. Я правильно понимаю? У меня есть записи толпы и записи диктора, которого хочу распознать. X-vector говорите лучше ? Насколько я понял это усредненные значения последнего скрытого слоя для от всех входных фреймов. После усредненные стат значения подаются на след сеть, где уже принимается решение относительно того кто говорит. Верно? Можно по идеи самому реализовать попробовать, тем более я примерно так и делал, только пытался просто обучить DNN без усреднения и подачи на след DNN.